# How can I open the File > Import function in Google Sheets with a script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I wanted to specify that I've got the code below as the starting point of a much longer script.  This works as intended, but requires the user to know the name of the file in Drive in order to type it in.  I want to replace this part of my script with a different piece that instead allows the user to look at the files in their drive and select the text file to import and then pass on to the next section of script.**

I have the code below that I've put together and it asks the user for a file name, but I'd rather open the File > Import dialog and allow the user to select the file that it loads into the script for scrubbing. I've tried using the File Picker code to process this but it opens the file in a smaller dialog window and I'm not sure if it's possible to pass it into the script to scrub it. And when I used that dialog it generated an error when attempting to open a *.csv/*.txt and stated that Google failed to connect.

I've played with the Picker script function that I've found elsewhere which looks like it could work, but I'm not sure how to take the file selected and then continue on to the next part of my script.

**Picker script**

```
/**
 * Creates a custom menu in Google Sheets when the spreadsheet opens.
 */
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Picker')
      .addItem('Start', 'showPicker')
      .addToUi();
}

/**
 * Displays an HTML-service dialog in Google Sheets that contains client-side
 * JavaScript code for the Google Picker API.
 */
function showPicker() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog.html')
      .setWidth(600)
      .setHeight(425)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, 'Select a file');
}

function doSomething(data){
  Logger.log('Your sheet ID selected ' + data.docs[0].id);
  Logger.log(data);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
}

/**
 * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token so that it can be passed to Picker.
 * This technique keeps Picker from needing to show its own authorization
 * dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope that Picker needs is
 * available in Apps Script. In this case, the function includes an unused call
 * to a DriveApp method to ensure that Apps Script requests access to all files
 * in the user's Drive.
 *
 * @return {string} The user's OAuth 2.0 access token.
 */
function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
}
```

**HTML Script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons.css">
  <script>
    // IMPORTANT: Replace the value for DEVELOPER_KEY with the API key obtained
    // from the Google Developers Console.
    var DEVELOPER_KEY = 'My key is here';
    var DIALOG_DIMENSIONS = {width: 600, height: 425};
    var pickerApiLoaded = false;

    /**
     * Loads the Google Picker API.
     */
    function onApiLoad() {
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': function() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
      }});
     }

    /**
     * Gets the user's OAuth 2.0 access token from the server-side script so that
     * it can be passed to Picker. This technique keeps Picker from needing to
     * show its own authorization dialog, but is only possible if the OAuth scope
     * that Picker needs is available in Apps Script. Otherwise, your Picker code
     * will need to declare its own OAuth scopes.
     */
    function getOAuthToken() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createPicker)
          .withFailureHandler(showError).getOAuthToken();
    }

    /**
     * Creates a Picker that can access the user's spreadsheets. This function
     * uses advanced options to hide the Picker's left navigation panel and
     * default title bar.
     *
     * @param {string} token An OAuth 2.0 access token that lets Picker access the
     *     file type specified in the addView call.
     */
    function createPicker(token) {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && token) {
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            // Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS)
            // Hide the navigation panel so that Picker fills more of the dialog.
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            // Hide the title bar since an Apps Script dialog already has a title.
            .hideTitleBar()
            .setOAuthToken(token)
            .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .setOrigin(google.script.host.origin)
            // Instruct Picker to fill the dialog, minus 2 pixels for the border.
            .setSize(DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.width - 2,
                DIALOG_DIMENSIONS.height - 2)
            .build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
      } else {
        showError('Unable to load the file picker.');
      }
    }

    /**
     * A callback function that extracts the chosen document's metadata from the
     * response object. For details on the response object, see
     * https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/result
     *
     * @param {object} data The response object.
     */
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
        google.script.run.doSomething(data);
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }

    /**
     * Displays an error message within the #result element.
     *
     * @param {string} message The error message to display.
     */
    function showError(message) {
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + message;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick='getOAuthToken()'>Select a file</button>
    <p id='result'></p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I read it correctly, you get your csv file at `csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();`. So that would be where I add the code to "continue on to the next part of my script."

Comment: Do you know for a fact that you’ll always have one file with a certain file name. If not then you may want to collect an excerpt from every file into a dialog and choose which file you want.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is understand how to open a dialog box to select my file _instead_ of using this method if possible so that I can pick the file instead of having to know the file name.  @Tedinoz I currently have a lot more script after this that works correctly, my problem is if I'm using the Picker script/function, how do I pass the file selected into the script here instead of using what I'm currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Picker](https://developers.google.com/picker/) to achieve what you desire, please follow the steps in this link:

## [File-open dialogs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#file-open_dialogs)

Let Know if it works for you

## Edit

After doing all previous steps, in your Apps Script code create a function with any name you want and an argument

```
function doSomething(data){
  Logger.log('Your Sheet ID selected ' + data.docs[0].id);
  Logger.log(data);
  // with the id you could use SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  // and then do all you want to do
}
```

Then call it in your pickerCallback function in your html using the class ***google.script.run***:

`google.script.run.doSomething(data);`

The pickerCallback function will look like this:

```
function pickerCallback(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
      if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
        var id = doc[google.picker.Document.ID];
        var url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];
        var title = doc[google.picker.Document.NAME];
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
            '<b>You chose:</b><br>Name: <a href="' + url + '">' + title +
            '</a><br>ID: ' + id;
        // Pass Values to your script
        google.script.run.doSomething(data);
      } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Picker canceled.';
      }
    }
```

### Notice

As this part of the code in the html says

```
// Instruct Picker to display only spreadsheets in Drive. For other
            // views, see https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews
            .addView(google.picker.ViewId.SPREADSHEETS)
```

You need to change those parameters if you want to open other types of files

Comment: I mentioned that I've tried that, but I don't know how to pass the file selection into the next part of the script

Comment: Oh ok I get it now, sorry for misunderstanding your question, I will recheck and edit my answer when I have the solution

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take a look at that and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to get back to you, however I've been trying to work on this issue and I still can't get it working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  When I run this, all it does is displays the file ID and name in the dialog box and then doesn't progress to anything else.

Comment: I actually edited my question with my current scripts